# How to add two new parameters to all Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am having a problem with my defined routes in Laravel. Until now, all of our URL structures contained one to four parameters. For a fictitious example

```
example.com/product
example.com/product/make
example.com/product/make/model
example.com/product/make/model/colour
```

With two, three or four parameters, I had specific routes created. For urls with just one parameter, I used a catch-all route.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomePageController@index');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'my_middleware'], function()
{
    Route::get('{product}/{make}', 'MakeController@index');
    Route::get('{product}/{make}/{model}', 'ModelController@index');
    Route::get('{product}/{make}/{model}/{colour}', 'ColourController@index');

    Route::get('{product}', 'DefaultController@index');
});
```

I now have a requirement to add two new parameters to every URL - One for the site country and one for the site area. So for example, a url could be:

```
example.com/uk/suffolk/product/make
```

I have achieved this by adding `'prefix' => '{country}/{area}'` to my route group. But this leaves me with a problem. What happens if someone uses my old URL structure - i.e. without the two new parameters. How can I get my routes to differentiate between the following urls - both of which have three parameters

```
example.com/product/make/model
// AND
example.com/uk/essex/product
```

We cater to around 30 countries, each of which have up to 5 areas. Would I need to do some validation in my Middleware or is there a better solution?

Comment: You could prepend the URL with an `country` segment of the URL. e.g. `http://example.com/country/uk/essex/product`. Then repeat the product routes for urls containing `/country` within a route group.

Comment: add security at you `route` for nothing changue you `url` display error

Comment: Have you considered using your existing sitemap and creating redirects?

Comment: @Devon. I have not considered that. I will investigate. Ideally there would be an automatic solution rather than a manual redirect, but this could work

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you could attempt an automatic redirect in a middleware if the country isn't found in your database and maybe a product with $country part of the request is? From my experience though, It's not abnormal to write out a bunch of 301s when making a large uri change.

Comment: *"What happens if someone uses my old URL structure - i.e. without the two new parameters."* Is this a case you need to worry about? Do you need to handle both cases? I would think with correct UI/UX you wouldn't, as no one should be manually navigating to one route vs the other. But, if you need to handle it take `example.com/example-product` as an example; with correct validation (fetch Country from DB with URL param), this would fail with something like "Unable to find Country with name of **example-product**".